# T-SQL Update Cell Based On Another Cell in Same Column for X Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
ID | Col1 | Col2 | ColX
------------------------
A  | 10   | 20  | V
B  | 15   | 5   | W
C  | 20   | 10  | X
D  | 25   | 10  | Y
E  | 30   | 0   | Z
```

I would like the value `D/Col1` (25) to become the value of that cell plus the value of `B1/Col1` (15) to become 40

Then for the value `D/Col2` (10) to become the value of that cell plus the value of `B/Col2` (5) to become 15

Similarly the value `D/ColX` (Y) to become the value of that cell plus the value of `B/Col2` (W) to become whatever W = Y is

At the end, I'd like for row B to be deleted (easy enough) to produce something like

```
ID | Col1 | Col2 | ColX
------------------------
A  | 10   | 20   | V
C  | 20   | 10   | X
D  | 40   | 15   | W+Y
E  | 30   | 0    | Z
```

There could be any amount of columns and values, as represented by the letters. I got the following to work for a single column update)

```
  UPDATE [table]
  SET [Col1]= (
  SELECT SUM([Col1]) FROM [table] WHERE [ID] IN('B','D')
  )
  WHERE [ID]='D'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `B/Col2`? It is 5.. right? You put `W`...

Comment: Yes - updated with a working example for a single column

Comment: At a given point in time how do you know which rows are being acted on? Is this to be a stored procedure relying on parameters? Or is there some kind of self-join not outlined here?

Comment: It'll always be where ID=B and ID=D